# How to change color of fontawesome icons in modular css React

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

This is folder structure of `<MessageHeader />` component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import style from '../css/MessageHeader.css';
import { fa, fa_question } from '../icons/icons';

    class MessageHeader extends Component {
        render(){
            return(

                <div className={style.container}>
                    <span className={[fa, fa_question].join(' ')} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default MessageHeader;
```

This is icons.js file

```
import fontAwesome from 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

const { fa, 'fa-question':fa_question } = fontAwesome;

export {
    fa,
    fa_question
}
```

**Now I want to add this:**

```
.fa-question {
    color: white
  }
```

How do I do it . Please Help I am new to react ecosystem.

Comment: you can directly specify using classname or in style likw `<span className="fa fa-tachometer" style={{color:  #87B87F}}></span>`

Comment: This is how you should use it:
[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you are using `create-react-app` to create your project.
you can create a style.css file on your project (next to icon.js file for example ) and then import it to your project.

```
import "./style.css";
```

also you can use inline style as Revansiddh mentioned in comment.

```
<span className={[fa, fa_question].join(' ')} style:{{color: "#FFF"}} />
```